# custom post type single page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, single

I have a custom post type called "listing" and am using a template called content-own.php to display all of my listings. In that page I am using:

```
<a href="<?php echo str_replace( home_url(), '', get_permalink($post->ID) ); ?>
```

to get a link to each single listing. When I click that link it shows all of the listings on that page instead of just that single listing. The template I am using for the single listing is single-listing.php which directs to content-listing.php. There I have:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($post-
>post_name); ?>>
  <div class="container mainPage">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="entry-content col-sm-9">
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'listing');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
           <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 box no-gutters">
             <?php sd_template_post_thumbnail();
                the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?>
                <span><?php the_field('price'); ?></span>
                <span><?php the_field('description'); ?></span>
                <span><?php the_field('style'); ?></span>
                <span><?php the_field('design'); ?></span>
           </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--entry-content col-sm-9-->
<div class="sideContact col-sm-3">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!--sideContact-->
</div><!--row-->
</div><!--entry-content-->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

So I'm not sure if I am doing something incorrectly with the way my templates are set up or with the loop on the content-listing.php page. Hopefully I explained this correctly, I'm fairly new to custom post types and Wordpress.

Comment: why are you using a custom query and loop in content-listing.php? the defaiult loop should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single page already, you shouldn't be using a wp_query as well.

Instead of these lines:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'listing');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Use these lines:

```
<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I see now that was causing the issue, as it's new to me I didn't realize I didn't need the wp_query